# how to get only text from clicking "a" tag using jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have created alphabetic list items using like this

```
<ul class="search_a_m nav nav-tabs" id="getAlpha">
       <?php

             foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {

                $default = "";
                $default = $char == 'A' ? 'active' : "";

        ?>
         <li class="nav-item"><a href="#<?php echo $char;?>" class="<?php echo $default;?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $char;?></a></li>
           <?php 
                }
           ?>
 </ul>
  <h1>
        <div id="titleh1"></div>
   </h1>
```

[image]

when I click any alphabetic button it will return below title I have get this using jquery:

```
let sBtn = document.getElementById('getAlpha')

    document.getElementById("titleh1").innerHTML = "A";

    if(sBtn){
        sBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {

            let btnid = e.target.textContent

            console.log(btnid)

            document.getElementById("titleh1").innerHTML = btnid;


        })
    }
```

But It will be getting errors when clicking outside of list items

See below image error I clicked red marks places and getting this error: 
[image]

So need to fix this error why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class at `<a>` element, like this:

```
<ul class="search_a_m nav nav-tabs" id="getAlpha">
    <?php
        foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
            $default = "";
            $default = $char == 'A' ? 'active' : "";
            echo '<li class="nav-item">'.
                    '<a href="#'.$char.'" class="Alpha" data-toggle="tab">'.$char.'</a>'.
                '</li>';        
        }
    ?>
</ul>
<h1><div id="titleh1"></div></h1>
```

then use selector classname:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Alpha');
    document.getElementById("titleh1").innerHTML = "A";

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            let btnid = this.text;
            console.log([this, btnid]);
            document.getElementById("titleh1").innerHTML = btnid;
        });
    }
```

Comment: its working fine for me, So when `this.text` is a perfect example, right

Comment: yups. you can look all data that you clicked at console `this`. Accepted that question, please.